# How to improve performance and make my flutter code concise?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

I am working on a Live TV app.It had a vertical list view which has many subdivision.Each subdivision has a horizontal list view.This is how the app looks like: https://youtu.be/R023PN289RM

The problem is I have to use the API's to each data.Let it be the profile pic,title and subtitle ,for each and every thing I am loading the data and copying it into an Array and from there I am displaying it.So it is a very repetitive thing I am doing and I feel it is not good.Also the app is lagging because it is has to load so much of data and I just want to know is there a way I can do to improve this:

The way I am tackling this issue is for the given
Json(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1saJN3MQvG55M1ipf42-65Etowi_kW80gkrosU6vBb5o/edit?usp=sharing)

I have made a PODO file which is here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1un989A1xn4mo5wz-7KrQTSwQJGkJihKpAqdlZSbaQPE/edit?usp=sharing

Then I have made a service file will load the data.I am including only 2 functions for the sake of simplicity or else it will become very lengthy

```
class Services {
  static const String url =
      "https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v3/home?pageLocation=home&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
      "user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";

  static Future<List<String>> loadDataForMovieId() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there");
      final homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);
      print("homeBannerlist is there");
      print("response .............");
      print(res.body);

      // print (homePage.homeBanners);
      HomeBanner homeBannerObject = new HomeBanner();
      List<String> homeBannerObjectMovieIdList = [];
      for (homeBannerObject in homePage.homeBanners)
        homeBannerObjectMovieIdList.add(homeBannerObject.movieId);
      print("Movie ID list is there");

      print(homeBannerObjectMovieIdList);
      return homeBannerObjectMovieIdList;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<List<String>> loadDataForMovieIdofPopularMovieSection() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there");
      final homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);
      HomeBanner homeBannerObject = new HomeBanner();
      List<String> homePageObjectPopularMovieID = [];
      for (homeBannerObject in homePage.movies)
        homePageObjectPopularMovieID.add(homeBannerObject.movieId);
      print("Movie ID list is there");

      print(homePageObjectPopularMovieID);
      return homePageObjectPopularMovieID;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

There are 10-15 load functions like this to load different elements like this:
[image: Service file screenshot.Each line you see is a function which is just adding elements to a list and returning them after the await statement like the code above]

Then in the initstate I am loading like this

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    handleScroll(); // function which is responsible for updating the isScrollingDown variable whenever the user scrolls down

    Services.loadDataForMovieId().then((movieIdList) {
      setState(() {
        _homeBannerObjectMovieIdList = movieIdList;
      });
    });

    Services.loadDataForMovieIdofPopularMovieSection().then((movieIdList) {
      setState(() {
        _popularMoviesMovieId = movieIdList;
      });
    });
    Services.loadDataForPopularTvShowSection().then((homePageSeriesPosterList) {
      setState(() {
        _seriesData = homePageSeriesPosterList;
      });
    });
```

Like this there are 10-15  Services.loadDataFor.......... functions in the init state function

Then in the listView or GridView builder I am using these arrays to display the pics,titles,sub-titles and other things.

It is working fine,but taking lots of time to load.ALso as you can see things are very repetitive.How do you really write a concise code and improve the performance as well?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case is **refactoring your API.**

Making **15 network requests** on app start before your user can do anything is too heavy. I would suggest changing your API such that it returns you all the data in one request.

Instead of manually querying the data for each section, you can create one endpoint on the server side that returns all sections in one go. This will save time, because in a mobile network request you have the [Round Trip Delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay) for every single network request.